# VS Code MySQL. Кодировка в блоке Result

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-code

Используется для VS Code MySQL из MarketPlace. Таблицы в БД представлены в кодировке UTF-8. В настройках VS Code стоит UTF-8 В результате выдает кракозябры. Сохранить как-либо это не могу. Как решить данную проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В цепи от таблицы БД до экрана - хренова гора кодировок. И возможных точек преобразования кодировки, соответственно. Вот всю эту цепочку нужно пройти и проверить. Сервер-БД-таблица-поле-коннектор-клиентская станция-приложение-переменная-консоль и всё остальное.

Comment: Проверить кодировку таблицы, столбцов, подключения к БД. Как вариант использовать workbench...возможно так вы быстрее найдете проблему